# Funcionamiento de UUID y ShortId

Tags: nodejs

Tengo una duda que es mas teoría que otra cosa.

Quisiera saber como es que funcionan los módulos o paqueterias (A decir verdad no se cual es el termino correcto) de node `UUID` y `ShortId`para que generen un Id único y que no se repita, mi motivo de la pregunta no es saber como funciona a fondo detalle por detalle sino mas bien saber como es posible que no se repita el Id.

De acuerdo a mi lógica el Id es generado aleatoriamente con un algoritmo pero en algún momento se tendría que repetir aunque fuera con una probabilidad mínima, no se si esto sea cierto ya que no conozco mucho del tema pero de ser el caso de que el Id se pueda repetir entonces como es posible generar un verdadero Id que jamas se repita en un proyecto y también ¿Que tanto recomiendan usar `UUID` y `ShortId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para entender como funcionan los **UUID** y también la librería [ShortId](https://github.com/dylang/shortid) y por qué son realmente únicos hay que entrar un poco en detalle de matemáticas y probabilidades.

Según la Wikipedia en ingles:

> To put these numbers into perspective, the annual risk of a given person being hit by a meteorite is estimated to be one chance in 17 billion, which means the probability is about 0.00000000006 (6 × 10−11), equivalent to the odds of creating a few tens of trillions of UUIDs in a year and having one duplicate. In other words, only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for approximately 100 years would the probability of creating a single duplicate reach 50%.

Parafraseando, si generamos algunas decenas de trillones (trillones estadonidense, es decir billones en español) de UUID la probabilidad de que entre esos haya uno duplicado es la misma que la probabilidad de ser alcanzado por un meteorito, en números 0.00000000006.

Dicho de otra forma, luego de generar mil millones de UUID por segundo durante 100 años, la probabilidad de generar uno duplicado asciende al 50%.

Entonces, si lo vemos de esa forma, según la teoría está garantizado que mientras los UUID sean generados con suficiente aleatoridad no hay riesgo de que se repitan en la cotidianidad. Entonces todo va depender de como fije el estandar la generación de los números aleatorios, a lo largo del tiempo se han usado distintos métodos. De esto ya nos advierte el articulo:

> However, these probabilities only hold when the UUIDs are generated using sufficient entropy. Otherwise, the probability of duplicates could be significantly higher, since the statistical dispersion might be lower. Where unique identifiers are required for distributed applications, so that UUIDs do not clash even when data from many devices is merged, the randomness of the seeds and generators used on every device must be reliable for the life of the application. Where this is not feasible, RFC 4122 recommends using a namespace variant instead.

Si quieres darle una mejor revisada al tema de como se generan los números aleatorios, te recomiendo esta [lectura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Te invito a leer [answer]. En el sitio evitamos responder preguntas de este estilo, ya que no son específicas y suelen basarse en opiniones. Otra sugerencia que te puedo dar, si tu respuesta incluye una cita a alguna documentación, y la misma sólo está disponible en otro idioma, sería fantástico que pudieras hacer una traducción de la misma. No es necesaria una traducción profesional, pero si lo suficientemente buena, para que sea válida y entendible. Tóma esto en cuenta para futuras respuestas. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio, muchas gracias por las sugerencias, las tendré en cuenta para mis próximas respuestas aquí en StackOverflow.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero por favor ayúdanos a responder preguntas creadas de acuerdo a lo descrito en el Centro de ayuda, específicamente [ask], saludos.